# Simple Django model design concept...need input?

Tags: django

I have a simple product database with the following:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class meta:
        abstract = True

class Shoe(Product): #inherits from product
    size = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Computer(Product): #inherits from product
    cpu = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

This leaves 2 tables in the DB...Shoe and Computer. Now what if I want to organize them by category? As in have a Category model with a nice human-readable name, an icon for displaying on the product drop-down menu, and suchlike. I'm lost! Shoe and Computer are different models...so how can one model (Category) organize them?

HALP?

Comment: You need [generic foreign keys](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#id1) - which (as their name suggests) are foreign keys that can link to more than one model. See @dm03514's answer for details.

Comment: With generic foreign keys in Category, every category would have at most one product. I highly doubt that is what he needs. Anyway the question is not clear enough to say that.

Answer (score 1):

Just put this into Product:

```
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='%(class)s_set')
```

You can learn more about foreign keys [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey).

Comment: There is no Product table. There is only Shoe and Computer in this example (Product is abstract).

Your code would leave me with both Shoe and Computer having a foreign key to Category, yet no single model I could manipulate to list all products.

Comment: I think it is better to work with Shoes and Computers separately in your application. For that you could also make ShoeCategory and ComputerCategory and have separate foreign keys for Computer and Shoe. That would be a way I would do it. It does not mean that you would need e.g. more views to handle each model separately. You can have just one view that translates url param into an appropriate Product child. If you really want to work with all the product types together, then there is multi-table inheritance for that. I wouldn't go this way but maybe that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use [Generic Foreign Keys](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/)

```
class Category(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    name = models.charField(max_length=50)

class Product(models.Model):
    categories = generic.GenericRelation(Category)
```

I"m not quite sure what you had in mind for categories, but you can create new categories referencing any object, Computer or Shoe

```
shoe = Shoe.object.get(pk=1)
category = Category(content_object=shoe, name='tennis')
category.save()
category = Category(content_object=shoe, name='waterproof')
category.save()
shoe.catetories.all()
```

Comment: I think this is something like what I am looking for...except I don't need multiple categories of shoe (like tennis or waterproof), but merely one category called "shoe" that points to a model called shoe (that holds shoe-specific data). And another category called computer that points to a model that holds computer-specific data.

Does this make sense? This way, I could have ONE model (category) that I could loop through, find all of my product models, and list each item of that model.